# Question about theorem relating differentiability of $f$ to that of $f_1,\dots,f_m$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$\newcommand{\mbf}{\mathbf}$
First we define $Df(a)$ as the unique linear transformation $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb  R^m$ such that
$$\lim_{\mbf h\to\mbf 0}\frac{|f(\mbf a+\mbf h)-\mbf f(\mbf a)-Df(\mbf a)(\mbf h)|}{|\mbf h|}=0$$
and $f'(a)$ is the $m\times n$ matrix of this transformation.

The theorem:

> If $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$, then $f$ is differentiable at $a\in\mathbb R^n$ if and only if each $f_i$ is, and
> $$Df(a)=(Df_1(a),\dots,Df_m(a)).$$
> Thus $f'(a)$ is the $m\times n$ matrix whose $i$th row is $(f_i)'(a)$.

I understand the first part, but why does $Df(a)=(Df_1(a),\dots,Df_m(a))$ imply that $f'(a)=\begin{pmatrix}f_1'(a)\\\vdots\\f_m'(a)\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: One minor point. I believe the theorem you quote is missing some assumptions. The forward direction is fine: If $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then the partial derivatives exist etc. In the reverse direction, you need the partial derivatives to exist **and be continuous in an open set containing $a$** in order to guarantee that $f$ is differentiable at $a$.

Comment: @Mark You are right, but your point has nothing to do with the question. This only concerns the matrix representation of $Df(a)$ and does not claim that the existence of partial derivatives implies that $f$ is differentiable at $a$.

Comment: @Paul Frost I'm well aware it doesn't affect the OP's question. That's why it's a comment and not an answer. Regardless, as stated, the theorem is incorrect, and I wanted to point that out.

Comment: @Mark I do not think there is a mistake in the theorem. If all coordinate functions $f_i$ of $f$ are differentiable at $a$, then $f$ is differentiable at $a$. This does not involve any partial derivatives.

Comment: @Mark: No, it is correct. A function $g:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ converges to $y\in\mathbb R^n$ if and only if its components converge to the components of $y$. Then note that $\vert g(x)\vert$ converging to $0$ is equivalent to $g(x)$ converging to $0$. Apply these to the function $g(h):=\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-\mathrm Df(a)(h)}{\vert h\vert}$.

Comment: @Paul Frost and co. You two are correct. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal L(n,m)$ denote the set of linear maps $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$. We have $Df(a) \in \mathcal L(n,m)$ and $Df_i(a) \in \mathcal L(n,1)$. Thus, strictly speaking, the equation
$$Df(a) = (Df_1(a),\ldots,Df_m(a)) \tag{1}$$
does not make sense because the LHS is an element of $\mathcal L(n,m)$ and the RHS an element of $\mathcal L(n,1)^m = \mathcal L(n,1) \times \ldots \times  \mathcal L(n,1)$ ($m$ factors). But $\mathcal L(n,m) \ne \mathcal L(n,1)^m$. However, there is a natural isomorphism
$$\phi : \mathcal L(n,m) \to \mathcal L(n,1)^m, \phi(g) = (\pi_1 \circ g,\ldots,\pi_m \circ g) \tag{2}$$
where $\pi_i : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$ is the projection onto the $i$-th coordinate. Its inverse is given by
$$\left(\phi^{-1}(g_1,\ldots,g_m)\right)(\xi) = \sum_{i=1}^m g_i(\xi) e_i \tag{3}$$
where $e_i$ is the standard $i$-th basis vector of $\mathbb R^m$.

The strict meaning of $(1)$ is that $\phi(Df(a)) = (Df_1(a),\ldots,Df_m(a))$. This comes from the fact that $Df_i(a) =D(\pi_i \circ f)(a) = D\pi_i (f(a)) \circ Df(a) = \pi_i \circ Df(a)$.

The equation $(1)$ is an *abuse of notation*, but I think it is acceptable. If you want, you can also write
$$Df(a)(\xi) = \left(\phi^{-1}(Df_1(a),\ldots,Df_m(a))\right)(\xi) = \sum_{i=1}^m Df_i(a)(\xi) e_i. $$
Now let us come to matrices. If $g \in \mathcal L(n,m)$ is represented by the $m \times n$-matrix $A$, then $\pi_i \circ g \in \mathcal L(n,1)$ is represented by the $1 \times n$-matrix $R_i(A)$ given by the $i$-th row of $A$. This is fairly obvious, but if you want to prove it formally, observe that $\pi_i$ is represented by the $1 \times m$-matrix $P_i = (p_{1j})$ with $p_{1j} = 0$ for $j \ne i$ and $p_{1i} = 1$. Then $\pi_i \circ g$ is represented by the $1 \times n$-matrix $P_i \circ A = R_i(A)$.

This gives the desired representation of $f'(a)$. Simply observe that $Df(a)$ is represented by the $m \times n$-matrix $f'(a)$ whose $i$-th row $R_i(f'(a))$ is the $1 \times n$-matrix $P_i \circ f'(a)$ which represents $\pi_i \circ Df_i(a) = Df_i(a)$. This shows $R_i(f'(a)) = f'_i(a)$.

Answer (score 0):

What is $f_i'$ but the gradient $\nabla f_i=(\partial f_i/\partial x_1,\dots,\partial f_i/\partial x_n)$, and thus the $i$th row of the Jacobian?

Comment: I haven't learned about gradients or partial derivatives yet. Only some basic theorems about derivatives. Could you answer the question without using these?

Comment: Oh boy... I think you should spend some time doing lots of problems involving gradients and partial derivatives before handling this material

Comment: I'm not sure how to off the top of my head.  It's a beautiful theory but can also resemble a huge morass that I don't know how to separate out.

Comment: @mathstudent334 If we defined $f(x,y,z)=(xyz,x^2+yz)$ would you be able to compute $f'(x,y,z)?$

Comment: I am able to compute the derivates of $xyz$ and $x^2+yz$. If I assume that $f'(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}f_1'(x,y,z)\\f_2'(x,y,z)\end{pmatrix}$ then I am able to compute $f'(x,y,z)$ but this is was my question.

Comment: If $f(x,y,z)=(xyz,x^2+yz)^T$ then the total derivative of $f$ at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is$$df(x_0,y_0,z_0)=\Big(y_0z_0dx+x_0z_0dy+x_0y_0dz,2x_0dx+z_0dy+y_0dz\Big)^T$$
The first component $y_0z_0dx+x_0z_0dy+x_0y_0dz$ is what you call $df{_1}(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ while the second component $2x_0dx+z_0dy+y_0dz$ is what you call $df_2(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. We can express this as a matrix vector product $$df(x_0,y_0,z_0)=\begin{bmatrix}y_0z_0&x_0z_0&x_0y_0\\2x_0&z_0&y_0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}dx\\dy\\dz\end{bmatrix}:=f'(x_0,y_0,z_0)\begin{bmatrix}dx\\dy\\dz\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Note if $(x,y,z)\approx (x_0,y_0,z_0)$ then

$$f(x,y,z) \approx \begin{bmatrix}y_0z_0&x_0z_0&x_0y_0\\2x_0&z_0&y_0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x-x_0\\y-y_0\\z-z_0\end{bmatrix}+f(x_0,y_0,z_0)$$